# Android App folder filesystem access

Tags: android, file-permissions

My question is related to filesystem access in Android apps. Suppose I want to grab a file that another app just downloaded? Can I access the other apps file / doc-folder from within my ohwn app? My first guess is no...

Thanks for clarification ;-)

Greets, pawi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that other app is downloading the file to the sdcard, and your application has permission to access the sdcard, then yes, you can grab the file.

But if the other apps downloading to the internal filesystem, it will not be possible to get the file, unless the other app is allowing your app to do so, by using permissions or intents.

Comment: Thank you Robert. That's what I expected - and how it should be done ;-)

Comment: ..asking further ;-) Is there some kind of public folder that apps can use? The 'other app' states that it has a file-export function. Of course it depends what they mean...

Comment: Again, for internal file system the answer is no. But for the sdcard there is a folder called download, created by the browser. That one seems sensible to use. It's really up to the 'other app' to decide which one to use, though. I recommend emailing the developer of the 'other app' and ask if it's not clear.